# custom navigation bar android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do a custom horizontal navigation bar, which consists of as many dots as i have pages.

My thoughts are:

1. Create a Custom ListView
2. Create Class Dot extends from View
3. Add all these dots to the custom listview dynamically..

Is this right to do so?

EDIT:

```
public class NavigationBarLesson extends LinearLayout {
    private LessonConfig config = LessonConfig.getInstance();
    private ArrayList<NavigationCircle> navigationCircles;
    private int pageCount;

    public NavigationBarLesson(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }   

    public NavigationBarLesson(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        Log.i("init","yes");
        pageCount = config.getLektionCount();
        navigationCircles = new ArrayList<NavigationCircle>();

        for(int i=0; i < pageCount; i++){
            this.addView(new NavigationCircle(context));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

}

public class NavigationCircle extends ImageView{
    private static Bitmap img;
    private Bitmap activeImg;


    public NavigationCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public NavigationCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }   

    public NavigationCircle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.upcoming_pages);
    }

    public Bitmap getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public Bitmap getActiveImg() {
        return this.activeImg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not see why you would need a ListView. Create a horizontal LinearLayout with some simple views like TextView's or ImageView's etc added dynamically to the LinearLayout.

Comment: Ok i add them now all in a for loop, with this.addView(new NavigationCircle(context));

So the onDraw hasnt to be used, this works well.

But how can i tell my Custom ListView, which of these dots is active at the moment, because this special one has to be drawn with another  drawable ressource.

Because my constructor can just be called once... i edit the example code above to my inital question.

Comment: While drawing your dots, check some var (an activity instance int variable for example) containing the id of the current 'active' or 'important' dot, and draw it differently. Also, add a click listener to it (obviously you can add a click listener to any view, ImageView too). You can add different click listeners to different dots, and even disable some listeners whenever you like.  Also, you can use a HorizontalScrollView instead of a LinearLayout or ListView which is suited for your purpose I guess. Good luck.